# How to set dynamic height to a PageView to show images in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I have a PageView that shows images:

```
  int _immaginiIndice = 0;
  final PageController _immaginiContr = PageController();

Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                child: PageView.builder(
                  controller: _immaginiContr,
                  onPageChanged: (i) {
                    setState(() => _immaginiIndice = i);
                  },
                  itemCount: _questoLuogo.immagini.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, int j) => Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          image: NetworkImage(applicazione['urlimm'] + 
                              _questoLuogo.immagini.elementAt(j)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Sorry for naming variables in my own language.

The height of the container is fixed to half the device, but the images have various aspect ratios, so some look bad. What I want is to fix the width at 100% to all images, but the height will be proportional, so both portrait and landscape images look fine.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are not giving a size to your second container but try something like that :

With to expanded widget with a flex of 1 both should separate your screen in two.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: AssetImage(
                  'images/backgroundImage.PNG',
                )),
          ),
        )),
    Expanded(flex: 1, child: Container()),
  ],
);
```

Comment: The first container is a child of a ListView. I want to remove it but I get error. With your code I can see the images not grainy, but cutted. If the height of the image overcomes the height of the container, I want to reduce the width to see the image not grainy and not cutted.